# C++Builder 10.2 - IDE automatically changes USEFORM macros to incorrect value when adding a file to the project

Tags: c++, forms, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am updating a VCL forms application originally written in C++Builder 5 to be used in C++Builder 10.2. For the most part I have this worked out, however the IDE keeps automatically updating its syntax to an incorrect value. In the projects main .cpp, it has various USEFORM macros, such as `USEFORM("Location.cpp", FrmLocation);`, and a corresponding line in the WinMain to set it up of the form `Application->CreateForm(__classid(TFrmSelect), &FrmSelect);`.

When I add an unrelated static library file to the project, the IDE automatically updates the USEFORM macros to `USEFORM("Location.cpp", frmLocation);` with a lower case f at the start of the form name. This of course means that the line in main no longer parses and the macro no longer links up to the form as it has changed the name to an incorrect value.

A simple find and replace of "frm" -> "Frm" fixes the issue, however I will need to perform the same update on several other old programs and would like to avoid having to process this manually for every single one of them. I would also quite like to know why the IDE is doing this so I can avoid running into such issues in future.

Comment: The `USE...` macros have been deprecated for a very long time, you shouldn't even be using them anymore.  Don't *migrate* (ie, open) projects from an older IDE to a newer IDE.  Create a whole new project in the newer IDE, and then *add* your existing source files to it as needed. Let the IDE manage the file references as it needs.

Comment: Not sure about this @RemyLebeau, If I create a brand new VCL C++ project with 11.2 (patch1) the file "Project1.cpp" contains a line: USEFORM("Unit1.cpp", Form1);

Comment: @RogerCigol Trust me, the macros are legacy, they don't actually do anything anymore, not during compiling, not in project management.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll try it and report back on Monday, though bear in mind I'm using a fairly old version of the IDE. I'll agree that the USELIB and USERES macros do indeed appear to have gone by the wayside, but the fact that I get a compile error when the single difference in the source file is those macro lines suggests to me that the USEFORMs are at least still considered by the compiler.

Comment: Can confirm that for my code/IDE version at least, the USEFORM macros are definitely still required for the application to compile.